# How to find translation of ImageView?

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

I drag Image view in following way.

```
matrix.postTranslate(a,b);
ImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

I want to find values `a` and `b`. I can get ImageView.getImageMatrix, but how to find translated way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);
```

The values array will now hold the translation floats. The x translation is

```
values[Matrix.MTRANS_X]
```

The y translation is

```
values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]
```